# Physics and calculus in blender

Tags: python, physics, animation-nodes, mathematics

I'm physics student and I want to calculate things on blender, I've to learn many things of the program and I'm starting on it. I want to know if it's possible to do some calculus inside blender, for example, create a sphere and clicking on a point of the surface for calculate the tangent of that point, that's all I want to know for start a project on relativity physics.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! If by calculus you mean numerical analysis, then yes, Blender can be used as a scientific computing package. Are you looking to create an interactive application? Or are you just looking to do some data analysis. How would you define the "tangent" of that point?

Comment: I used the simplest words, it's something weird to understand and never has made before, it's something more than "calculus", it includes linear algebra, mechanics, vectors and other fields of mathematics and physics... and it isn't a "tangent" but you can figured out like that.
I want an interactive application that can show the data for the "differential" of the surface.

Comment: If I understand what you are saying correctly, then yes, you can do discrete differential geometry in Blender.